# Object Type Conversion Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript. I am trying to convert Object. While trying to convert it's only printing Number not string. while printing string it shows complete object not string. Below is my code.

```js
let user2 = {
  name: "Akash",
  surName: "Jangra",
  age: 30,
  Salary: 25000,


  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
    console.log(`hint : ${hint}`);
    return hint == "string" ? `{name: "${this.name}"}, ${this.surName}` : this.Salary;
  }
};

console.log(user2);
console.log(+user2);

console.log(user2 + 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
console.log(`${user2}`);
```

When you do

```
console.log('' + user2);
```

Hint equals `default`

You have to 'tell' JavaScript what to convert to explicitly.
Examples:

```
var x = { test: 1 };

// Console log the object
console.log(x);

// Try to convert to number
console.log(0 + x);

// Try to convert to string
console.log(`${x}`);

// I thought this would work as wel, but is does not convert to 'string' but to 'default'
console.log('' + x);

// Try to bool
console.log(!!x);
```

Edit: Like ezotos said. This is really uncommon to do in javascript though.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a very uncommon practice. Object in JavaScript are usually keep primitive. Thus, only containing data.

I would suggest to create a function that takes your source object as an argument and returns the desired output.

If you need the functionality in such an object, think about using a `class` instead.

And overload the toString() method for example.